# Convert Gtk.TreeView into a text format

Tags: treeview, gtk, vala

I'm trying to export a Gtk.TreeView into a text format. This is like an export to text function on an application which presents data in a TreeView using the ListStore model.

Can someone help with a sample code on how to efficiently parse a Gtk.TreeView and represent it in a simple text format.

Comment: I think you'll need [to use something like this `GtkTreeModel` function](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkTreeModel.html#gtk-tree-model-get-value).

Comment: @oldtechaa Thanks for your response. However, one of the parameters to call the get_value function on the TreeModel is the TreeIter. I'm not sure how to get the TreeIter to loop over the TreeModel - public abstract void get_value (TreeIter iter, int column, out Value value)

Comment: See [example code in valadoc](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeStore).

Comment: And especially [example code in valadoc for Gtk.TreeIter](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeIter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point consider [this code from valadoc](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeIter):

```
public static int main (string[] args) {
    // Create a ListStore:
    Gtk.ListStore list_store = new Gtk.ListStore (2, typeof (string), typeof (int));
    Gtk.TreeIter iter;

    // Insert data: (0: State, 1: Cities)
    list_store.append (out iter);
    list_store.set (iter, 0, "Burgenland", 1, 13);
    list_store.append (out iter);
    list_store.set (iter, 0, "Carinthia", 1, 17);
    list_store.append (out iter);
    list_store.set (iter, 0, "Lower Austria", 1, 75);
    list_store.append (out iter);
    list_store.set (iter, 0, "Upper Austria", 1, 32);
    list_store.append (out iter);
    list_store.set (iter, 0, "Salzburg", 1, 10);
    list_store.append (out iter);
    list_store.set (iter, 0, "Styria", 1, 34);
    list_store.append (out iter);
    list_store.set (iter, 0, "Tyrol", 1, 11);
    list_store.append (out iter);
    list_store.set (iter, 0, "Vorarlberg", 1, 5);
    list_store.append (out iter);
    list_store.set (iter, 0, "Vienna", 1, 1);

    // Output:
    //  ``Entry: Burgenland     13``
    //  ``Entry: Carinthia      17``
    //  ``Entry: Lower Austria  75``
    //  ``Entry: Upper Austria  32``
    //  ``Entry: Salzburg       10``
    //  ``Entry: Styria         34``
    //  ``Entry: Tyrol          11``
    //  ``Entry: Vorarlberg     5``
    //  ``Entry: Vienna         1``
    for (bool next = list_store.get_iter_first (out iter); next; next = list_store.iter_next (ref iter)) {
        Value val1, val2;
        list_store.get_value (iter, 0, out val1);
        list_store.get_value (iter, 1, out val2);
        stdout.printf ("Entry: %s\t%d\n", (string) val1, (int) val2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should also read the [top level documentation for the Gtk.TreeModel interface](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeModel).